# Is std::map allocation static when possible?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider 3 versions of a code with the same effects:

Version 1:

```
int main()  {
    std::map<int,int> x = {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}};
    // Do some stuff...
    return 0;
}
```

Version 2:

```
int main()  {
    std::map<int,int> x;
    x[0] = 0;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 2;
    // Do some stuff...
    return 0;
}
```

Version 3:

```
int main()  {
    std::map<int,int> x;
    x.insert(std::pair<int,int>(0,0));
    x.insert(std::pair<int,int>(1,1));
    x.insert(std::pair<int,int>(2,2));
    // Do some stuff...
    return 0;
}
```

What is the efficiency of each of these codes?

I think that version 1 is a fully static allocation: space required by `x` is allocated once and values are set.
I also think that version 3 requires dynamic allocation: each call to insert will check if the key is not already used, check where to insert and allocate more space to map before assigning the value.
For version 2, I am not sure. Could you help me with that?

Comment: version 1 is not an assignment first of all.

Comment: there is no static allocation, because no matter how you insert the first 3 you can always (dynamically) add more

Comment: for int's it doesn't matter (probably).  For larger objects; x[] will default create the object first; so is slower. 0 and 3 are probably identical.  What did you see when you profiled it?

Comment: why do you care?

Comment: Version 2, for each key, inserts a node with this key and a value-initialized value and then performs assignment through the reference to this value. Version 1 is probably the best here. Allocation is not largely an issue here, though map implementation probably makes use of the fact that some of the elements are already known beforehand.

Comment: @user463035818 Why do I care about performance? Well I don't know, I probably want to be as slow as possible?

Comment: @user463035818: More seriously I am thinking about a huge std::map instantiation with generated code.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois then just don't use #2

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois choose proper algorithms and data structures, write readable and so maintainable code first, then worry about performance later if necessary.

Comment: very seriously: then you need to profile your code instead of speculating

Comment: I't's all going to be dynamic allocation, but option 1 does all the work up front. Probably save you some time, but the only way to be sure is measure.

Comment: @Slava: Worrying about performance late is only an opinion.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." Knuth

Comment: @Slava: you are speculating about the fact the part of the code is critical or not and so over-interpreting the question, which is only what it is, not about coding philosophy.

Comment: btw that quote is often quoted without the last sentence which imho is the key: you need to get the 97% right before you can profile to identify the 3% and that 3% are important

Comment: philosophical discussions aside, the question is of course worth considering, but still the only way to know for sure is to measure

Comment: I doubt that there is any real difference between the three versions. They are all just syntactic sugar for creating 3 tree nodes and inserting them into the tree.

Comment: @PaulFloyd That's what I suspect too but that would clearly be a lack of optimization if *Version 1* does not behave like I supposed it would.

Comment: @PaulFloyd no, they are definitely not just syntactic sugar. eg 1 is no assignment and 2 has considerable overhead

Comment: Version 3 should use `std::pair<const int, int>` (the map's `value_type`) otherwise a copy of the pair might be made (which could be optimized out).  Or use `try_emplace`.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard makes no requirements on whether the allocation happens at compile-time or run-time. All this means is that implementations are free to make their own optimizations (or not).

So the proper thing to do would be to test.

Most likely such optimizations have not been implemented. There is no `constexpr` constructor of `std::map`, despite the fact that the `std::initializer_list` you create here may be a compile-time constant (note that no aggregate initialization is being performed here either)

```
std::map<int,int> x = {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}};
```

Comment: How can allocation occur at compile time?

Comment: I mean small buffer optimization

Comment: Whilst I think that it should be possible to allocate all of the nodes in a single block of memory (in the case of the init list) I doubt that this happens in practice. Otherwise the only difference is in the number of function calls, for which the init list probably has an advantage.

Answer (score 3):

Although its implementation defined, `std::map`'s allocations is never static. It using an [RB tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)
as an underlying data structure in 99 cases of 100.
In your case, you have exactly the same time and space complexity in all three cases.

Comment: Then how can you explain the differences in the profiling tests? (See my own answer)

Comment: I cant tell unless I see your tests and approach

Comment: I generated the exact code in the question (except that instead of 3 entries I put 100,000), then compiled with `g++ -std=c++11` (no other flag). I'm currently doing it with optimizations but the compilation is very long so I still don't have the results.

Answer (score 1):

After all these speculations, I finally profiled the code. For this, I generated 3 codes like in the question, but with 100,000 entries. Here are the results, averaged on several runs, compiled with g++ with no optimization:

- Version 1: 26 ms (compile time: 2.5 s)
- Version 2: 80 ms (compile time: 10 s)
- Version 3: 73 ms (compile time: 37 s)

So clearly, the best solution is the first one. Both versions 2 and 3 are nearly equivalent at execution, but version 3 is really worse at compile time.

Comment: And with optimization? A lot of the std::map interface is in functions that can be inlined.

Comment: With optimization: 15 ms for version 1, 2.6 seconds of compilation, and the compilations have been running for hours for versions 2 and 3 and have still not finished...